# pysimplegui keyboard event returns question mark when pressing non-ascii character

Tags: python, events, unicode, hebrew, pysimplegui

I'm using pysimplegui and trying to receive keyboard events from the window.
I used the following initialization:

```
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, finalize=True, return_keyboard_events=True)
```

I receive keyboard events normally, but when a non-ascii key is pressed (like when using hebrew charachters), I only receive a question mark in the event.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is not exactly an answer but I cannot comment yet.

I am able to receive non-ascii characters in my console using Unicode combinations. I tried German, Turkish and Hebrew letters and they are all returned fine. Your problem could be due to operating system or IDE - (Win10 and PyCharm in my case). You could also try to encode/decode the event.